# MatLab to Python Euler Equation

Tags: python, matlab, for-loop, plot

So I am trying to learn python and I think a good way to do this is to take problem sets I had previously done in MatLab and convert them into Python. Here is the **MatLab** code that I am working with

```
% C14 halflife is 5726 years
% The time constant tau is t(1/2)/ln2 = 8260 y

N0=10000; %initialize N0
tau=8260; %Carbon 14 

tmax=40000; %max time value, will be on the x-axis

% Generate data using exact values
t1=linspace(0,tmax,100);
N1=N0*exp(-t1/tau);%Here we introduce the equation for nuclear decay
figure
plot1 = plot(t1,N1);

% Generate data using Euler

Step=1000;
N=N0;
NumRes=N;
tx=0:Step:tmax;
% This is the taylor series generation of data. 
for t=Step:Step:tmax

    N=N-Step*N/tau;
    NumRes=[NumRes,N];

end

% Plot the approximation

 hold on
plot2 = plot(tx,NumRes,'+');
```

I got the exact part of the solution down for python which is shown below. But I cannot get the approximation part.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def exact(NO, decay, tmax):
    t2 = np.linspace(0,tmax,100)
    N2 = NO * np.exp(-t2/decay)
    plt.plot(t2,N2)
exact(10000,8260,40000)
```

I can't figure out how to get the approximation part but nonetheless here is my attempt...

```
Step = 1000
N = 10000
tau = 8260
tx = xrange(0,40000,Step)
result= []
for i in xrange(Step,40000,Step):
    result = N - Step*N/tau

plt.plot(tx,result)
plt.show()
```

**Error Messages I am getting**

```
     plt.plot(tx,result)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3154, in plot
    ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1811, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1427, in plot
    for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 386, in _grab_next_args
    for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 364, in _plot_args
    x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 223, in _xy_from_xy
    raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension")
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension
```

I am very new to python and clearly my code is wrong. I would love for any help that you can provide.

Comment: What do you expect to see and what are you actually seeing?

Comment: @JamieBull I am currently just getting a lot of error messages which I will post. I will see if I can post the output from MatLab

Comment: Looks like your are using python 2 so `Step*N/tau` is an integer division, which might be your problem. Try converting `N` to a `float` before the loop.

Comment: @Holt still getting the error message. Thank you though

Comment: @AdamWarner The second problem is that you should append to `result` instead of overriding it. Try `result.append(N - N*Step/tau)` instead of `result = ...`.

Comment: @Holt that is yielding AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: @AdamWarner See my answer. And comment if it does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- You are overriding result instead of appending value to it.
- You are doing integer division `/` (because all operands are integer).
- You are looping over `xrange(Step, 40000, Step)` but `tx` is `xrange(0, 40000, Step)` so you will never have the same size for `tx` and `result`.

Here is a correction of your code:

```
Step   = 1000
N      = 10000.0 # Use a float instead of an int here
tau    = 8260
tx     = xrange(0, 40000, Step)
result = [N] # Start with a list containing only N
for i in xrange(Step, 40000, Step):
    N = N - Step * N / tau # Update N
    result.append(N) # Append N to result
plt.plot(tx, result)
plt.show()
```

Since you are using `numpy`, here is a more direct way of doing what you want:

```
tx = numpy.arange(0, 40000, Step)
ty = N * (1 - Step / tau) ** numpy.arange(0, tx.size)
```

Comment: did not work for me. I tried printing result.append(N) and I just got None repeatedly

Comment: @AdamWarner `result.append(N)` always return `None`. I think you are trying to store `result.append(N)` in `result`, you should not, see my code.

Comment: seems to work. Now I just need to figure out how to get the plotting. Which is what I am getting the error message on

Comment: @AdamWarner See my edited answer, `result` and `tx` did not have the same size since you were missing the initial `N` value.

Comment: thank you for all your help. I accepted your answer thank you for putting up with my nooby python skills.